# Update column in pandas dataframe without warning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd  
DF1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['abc in first line of text', 'abc of second line of text', 'def on third line of text'], 'other': [10, 20, 30]})  
DF2 = DF1[DF1.name.str.startswith('abc')]  
DF2['name'] = [x.split('abc')[1][4:].title() for x in DF2['name']]  
print(DF2)
```

Updating a column in a pandas dataframe using the code above gives the following warning:

> SettingWithCopyWarning:
>   A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.

The output is correct.

Any suggestions how to rewrite this code to prevent this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `assign`

```
DF2.assign(name=DF2.name.replace({'abc ':''},regex=True))
Out[46]: 
                     name  other
0   in first line of text     10
1  of second line of text     20
```

Or

```
DF2.assign(name=[x.split('abc')[1][4:].title() for x in DF2['name']])
Out[48]: 
                  name  other
0   First Line Of Text     10
1  Second Line Of Text     20
```

Comment: also, you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas